# Execute method on tabpage created in code

Tags: c#, winforms, events, tabpage

I have searched but cannot locate this problem.

On form 1 in code, I create a TabPage with a usercontrol in it and then add the TabPage to form1.TabControl and call public method LoadData on the usercontrol.
Problem: I need to reload the data when the new tabpage is activated or gains focus. If I did not create the tabpage in code, I could simply use TabControl's selectedIndex change event, but it needs to be created in code.
How can I do this?  Form 1:

```
private  void CreateNewTab()
    {

        TabPage tp1 = new TabPage();
        tp1.Text = "HSV";
        tp1.Name = "tpHSV";
        if (tabContMain.TabPages.ContainsKey(tp1.Name) == false)
        {
            HSVControl hsvc = new HSVControl();
            hsvc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            hsvc.LoadData();

            tp1.Controls.Add(hsvc);
            tabContMain.TabPages.Add(tp1);

        }

    }
```

====EDIT===============
Thanks for the comments. Let me try to explain my problem better.  The selectedIndex change event works fine.  I can access the tab by it's text or name.  The problem is calling the hsvc.LoadData() method.  I need to recall this method when the tab containing hsvc user control is clicked.  The LoadData() is public, but I cannot find a way to access it in Form1 (which holds the selectedIndex change event). I need a reference to hsvc control.

I added a property to the Form1 class like this:

```
private UserControl mControl;
```

then assigning it:

```
       HSVControl hsvc = new HSVControl();
       hsvc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       hsvc.LoadData();
       mControl=hsvc;
```

Then calling it in SelectedIndex change event, but it is still not visible there.

Comment: Use the same event here. You can assign event handler in code. See this msdn [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3). Or look into your designer generated code to see how it handles events. Or In your method write `tabContMain.SelectedIndexChange +=` and then press `Tab` key twice.

Comment: Seems like `TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged` should work fine.  What trouble are you having?  Is it just that you have no way to refer to hsvc in that event handler?  If so, simply add a field to your form class to hold a reference to it.

Comment: So call `hsvc.LoadData()` in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Right now I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`TabControl` Has a property called `SelectedTab`. use that property like:

```
private  void CreateNewTab()
{

    TabPage tp1 = new TabPage();
    tp1.Text = "HSV";
    tp1.Name = "tpHSV";
    if (tabContMain.TabPages.ContainsKey(tp1.Name) == false)
    {
        HSVControl hsvc = new HSVControl();
        hsvc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        hsvc.LoadData();

        tp1.Controls.Add(hsvc);
        tabContMain.TabPages.Add(tp1);
        tabContMain.SelectedTab = tp1;

    }

}
```

In that last line, It makes the `TabControl` to call its `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Then call LoadData event in this event:

```
private void TabControl_SelectedIndexChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //So Because Hsvc is a public field. I call its method here:
    if(TabControl.SelectedTab.Name = "My Desired Tab";
    {
        hsvc.LoadData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks again for the help.  The solution was kind of staring me in the face. I'm not sure it's the best, but this worked very well.

Created interface:

```
  public interface IControlBase
{
    void LoadData();
}
```

Had UserControl implement interface:

```
 HSVControl : UserControl,IControlBase
```

and having the existing LoadData() method on the usercontrol.

change

```
private UserControl mControl;
```

to

```
private IControlBase mControl;
```

Then in SelectedIndex change:

```
mControl.LoadData();
```

Comment: ...or you could have declared `mControl` as an `HSVControl` and skipped `IControlBase` entirely.

Comment: YEP, you're right.  Tested and works fine.  I'll leave it as an interface since I'll have more tabs with similar needs/controls.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: From a design perspective, the only advantage to defining an interface for this and future similar `TabPages` rather than referring to them strictly by their actual types is the ability to treat them generically (say, pass an array of them to a function that accepts them as `IControlBase` and calls `IControlBase` methods on them).  Even if the interface is required for such code, it's still probably best to *declare* the fields as instances of their actual types so you can call type-specific methods on them elsewhere in the code without first casting them back to their actual types.